# Proving f(rx) = rf(x)

Tags: real-analysis, functions

What's the difference between the proofs of $$ f(rx)= rf(x) \forall r \in \mathbb Z ,\forall x \in \mathbb R $$ and $$ f(rx)= rf(x) \forall r \in \mathbb Q , \forall x \in \mathbb R $$ where $ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ is an additive function.

Is there a way to prove that f(-x) = -f(x) without going through the above proofs?

Comment: Depends on how $f$ is described.

Comment: @Andre - f is said to be an additive function

Comment: Then yes, it does not require showing either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can prove the result without proving either of the items mentioned in the OP.

We are told that $f$ is additive, that is, $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$.

Put $x=0$. We get $f(0)=f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0)$. By subtraction, $f(0)=0$.

We have then $0=f(x+(-x))=f(x)+f(-x)$. From $f(x)+f(-x)=0$ the desired result follows.

As to the first part, to prove $f(rx)=rf(x)$ for rational $x$, it is useful to prove first that this holds for positive integers. Then for positive rationals $\frac{p}{q}$, where $q\gt 0$, we first prove that $f(\frac{x}{q})=\frac{1}{q}f(x)$ by considering $f\left(\frac{x}{q}+\frac{x}{q}+\cdots+\frac{x}{q}\right)$ ($q$ terms).

Comment: Ok I get it. If we are supposed to prove the $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Q $ scenarios after that, do I have to prove for positive and negative cases separately?

Comment: It is not absolutely necessary, but I think you will find it cleaner to do positives, and then the negatives are an easy consequence of $f(-x)=-f(x)$. Our intuition about positives is better, we are less likely to make a mistake.